# Extracting each same tag from the same class beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract all 'data-src' from this page. and then save the results to csv. There are several 'data-src' on this page all in the same class and I don't know how to deal with it.

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
from csv import writer


def test_list():
    with open('largeXDDDDDDDDDD.csv','w') as f1:
        writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
        #df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Lukasz\\Desktop\\PROJEKTY PYTHON\\W TRAKCIE\\large.csv")
        #url = df['LINKS'][1]
        url='https://paypalshop.x.yupoo.com/albums/81513820?uid=1'
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
        szukaj=soup.find_all('div',{'class':"showalbum__children image__main"})
        for XD in szukaj:
            q=(soup.find_all("data-src"))
            print(q)
        #q= soup.find("img", {"class": "autocover image__img image__portrait"})
        #q=(tag.get('data-src'))
test_list()```

HTML:
<div class="showalbum__children image__main" data-id="30842210">
     <div class="image__imagewrap" data-type="photo">
      <img alt="" class="autocover image__img image__portrait" data-album-id="83047567" data-frame="1" data-height="1080" data-origin-src="//photo.yupoo.com/ven-way/aac32ed1/2d2ed235.jpg" data-path="/ven-way/aac32ed1/2d2ed235.jpg" data-src="//photo.yupoo.com/ven-way/aac32ed1/big.jpg" data-type="photo" data-videoformats="" data-width="1080" src="//photo.yupoo.com/ven-way/aac32ed1/small.jpg"/>
      <div class="image__clickhandle" data-photoid="30842210" style="width: 1080px; padding-bottom: 100.00%" title="点击查看详情">
      </div>
````

Comment: Unrelated but to write a conformant csv file, you must open it with `newline=''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class selector for one of the children of the ones you are currently looking at to be at the right level. I use `select` and dict accessor notation to retrieve attribute. You cannot use with the syntax as you have written it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
from csv import writer


def test_list():
    #with open('largeXDDDDDDDDDD.csv','w') as f1:
        #writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
        url='https://paypalshop.x.yupoo.com/albums/81513820?uid=1'
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
        szukaj = soup.select('.image__portrait')
        for x in szukaj:
            q = x['data-src']
            print(q)

test_list()
```

Comment: Great. Can you explain how to export the results to the CSV file .. I can see these two lines commented out?

Comment: after add 'writer.writerow(q)'  is print weird things in Excel.